# Vanilla JavaScript: How to make the second number of two random numbers always higher than the first

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a children's math quiz and so far I have been able to do the following: Get two random numbers between 0 and 10 to appear; Make the + or - operator random; Give feedback if the answer is wrong or right; keep score;
There is one problem that I am facing though is that in some cases the operator will be - and the second random number will be greater than the first resulting in a - number answer.  As can be seen inside the code below, I have tried using an if statement within an if statement and also a while statement within an if statement.  Both do not produce the desired results.
I appreciate any advise on how to fix my problem.

Code:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", question);

var plusMinus = document.getElementById("plusMinus");
var counter = 0;

function question(){
  var startButton = document.getElementById("button1");
  var number1 = document.getElementById("number1");
  var number2 = document.getElementById("number2");
  var decider = Math.random();
  counter ++;

  if(decider<0.5){
    plusMinus.textContent = "+"  
  }
  else{plusMinus.textContent = "-"
  };

  button1.textContent = "Round" + counter;
  number1.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
  number2.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random()*11)

  /*Solution No.1 that failed:
  if(plusMinus.textContent == "-"){
    if(number2.textContent < number1.textContent){
      Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    }
  }
  else{Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
  }*/
  /*Solution No.2 that also failed:
  if(plusMinus.textContent == "-"){
    while(number2.textContent < number1.textContent){
      Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    }
  }
  else{Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
  }*/
};

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", answer);

var totalScore = 0;

function answer(){
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").textContent, 10);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").textContent, 10);
  var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById("userAnswer").value, 10);
  var feedBack = document.getElementById("feedBack");
  var scoreReport = document.getElementById("score");

  if (plusMinus.textContent == "+"){
    if(answer == num1 + num2) {
      feedBack.textContent = "Well Done!";
      totalScore = totalScore + 10;
    } 
    else {
      feedBack.textContent = "Try again!";
    }
  }
  else {
    if(answer == num1 - num2){
      feedBack.textContent = "Well Done!";
      totalScore = totalScore +10;
    } 
    else {feedBack.textContent = "Try again!"};
    }

  scoreReport.textContent = totalScore;
};
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/way81/r9vdLkzp/1/

Comment: Just a suggestion: You should consider storing your state somewhere else and have the DOM reflect that state.

Comment: Hello @Jeff, thanks for your advice, normally I keep my HTML, CSS and JS separate but to make it easier I just put it altogether when I am testing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if its minus. Check if the `number2` is bigger than the `number1` then swap them.

Something like this:

```
if(plusMinus.textContent == '-' && number2.textContent > number1.textContent) {
    var a = number2.textContent;
    number2.textContent = number1.textContent;
    number1.textContent = a;
}
```

When you call `answer()` you are getting the values again. So the fact that you swapped the order won't have any effects in the rest of your logic and you won't get any negative numbers.

**Snippet**:

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", question);

    var plusMinus = document.getElementById("plusMinus");

function question(){
    var startButton = document.getElementById("button1");
    var number1 = document.getElementById("number1");
    var number2 = document.getElementById("number2");
    var decider = Math.random();
    
    button1.textContent = "Again";
    number1.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    number2.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    
    if(decider<0.5){
      plusMinus.textContent = "+"  
    }
    else{plusMinus.textContent = "-"};
    
    if(plusMinus.textContent == '-' && number2.textContent > number1.textContent) {
        console.log('swapped')
        var a = number2.textContent;
        number2.textContent = number1.textContent;
        number1.textContent = a;
    }

};

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", answer);

function answer(){
    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").textContent, 10);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").textContent, 10);
    var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById("userAnswer").value, 10);
    var feedBack = document.getElementById("feedBack");
    var scoreReport = document.getElementById("score");
    var totalScore = 0;
     
      if (plusMinus.textContent == "+"){
        if(answer == num1 + num2) {
            feedBack.textContent = "Well Done!";
        } else {
          feedBack.textContent = "Try again!";
        }
      }
      else {
         if(answer == num1 - num2){
           feedBack.textContent = "Well Done!";
         } else {feedBack.textContent = "Try again!"};
      }

      for(count=0; count <=10; count++){
        if(plusMinus == "+" && answer == num1+num2){
            totalScore +1;
        }
        else if(plusMinus == "-" && answer == num1-num2){
            totalScore -1;
        }
      }

      scoreReport.textContent = totalScore;
};
```

```css
*{
  border: 2pt solid black;
}

p {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: impact;
  size: 16pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
<button id = "button1">Start!</button>
<p id = "number1"></p>
<p id = "plusMinus">+</p>
<p id = "number2"></p>
<input id = "userAnswer" type=text>
<button id = "button2">Answer</button>
<p id = "feedBack"></p>
<p id = "score">Score: 0</p>
</div>
<script src="randomMathsTest.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Joel, Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot.  One thing though, If you run your snippet long enough (click 'Again' enough times), you will run into a problem when the first number is 10, for example, I got a question of 6 - 10 and I was wondering why this is so.  But then I realised that JS is looking at it as 6 and a 1 even though it is ten.  It seems that JS was looking at it as string(?) so I altered your code as following and it has not had a problem so far, even when a - and a 10 are involved:

Comment: @Obi-wan just do a `parseInt` :)

Comment: Yes, Joel, that's what I was just going to say.   I am still new at writing comments and it took me a while to clarify my thoughts.   Thanks Joel

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first random number as an argument in creating the second random number. For instance:

```
var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
var num2 = num1+ Math.floor(Math.random()*(10-num1));
```

...or something similar. Just generate a random number between your first random number and 10 by creating a smaller range and adding the first number to the result.

**Addendum**

By following this method, you do skew the likelihood of larger numbers appearing in your problems. @Joel's answer would not suffer from this.

Comment: Hello Addendum,  Thanks for your help.  I tried your code and as @ConnorCMcKee said, the larger numbers were more prevalent.  Using Joel's answer seem to work when I also added parseInt( ).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalized solution you could use (it's not entirely adapted to your current code example, but I'm sure you'll be able to get it to work):

```
// create a random Boolean that determines whether it's minus
var isMinus = !Math.round(Math.random());

// create an array of two random numbers from 0-10
var numbers = [Math.floor(Math.random()*11), Math.floor(Math.random()*11)];

// if isMinus, sort numbers ascending, else keep as-is
numbers = isMinus ? numbers.sort().reverse() : numbers;

// assign the proper sign to the DOM element
plusMinus.textContent = isMinus ? '-' : '+';

// assign the proper array elements to the DOM elements
number1.textContent = numbers[0];
number2.textContent = numbers[1];
```